# Should I add another view to display the same page with one less field?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am just making the switch from WebForms to MVC and would like to ask what are the best ways of hiding particular fields in the view.  Assuming we have a model named WishList that has a list of gifts kids want for Christmas and the child's name.  We want the elves to view the list of gifts, but only Santa Claus can view the child's name.  Would it be best to have two views for the WishList (one for Santa and one for the elves) or is there another way to handle this?  My concern is that the number of views can start piling as high as the snow does in the North Pole by the time I enforce all of the visibility settings required in my application.

Comment: +1 for the colorful christmas simile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to hide the field using a client-side scripting language like jQuery, or you could actually put a bit of logic in the view itself that determines whether or not certain parts of the view are displayed.

Something like:

```
<% if (user.HasAccess) {%>
<input id="myInput" />
<%}%>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm going to give others a chance to answer before accepting in case there is an opposing opinion to your answer (since it seems to violate what I've read about MVC architecture keeping business logic out of the view(s)).

Comment: remember that "architecture" is a suggestion on how to do something, not an inviolable law. if you have a smaller site/app, don't be afraid to do stuff you're "not supposed to". if it saves you time and works how you want it, do it. if you're working on a larger system with a team of people, then i would suggest erring on the side of the "architecture laws". also, the state of some inputs being displayed is hardly "business logic" but what i would call "display logic" and totally acceptable in MVC.